# Accessing Paperclip module methods on rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I want to access the `s3_bucket` method that has access to the S3 bucket configured in my Rails app.

Looking at Paperclip source code I can see that is under Paperclip::Storage::S3 ([source code](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb)) module.

I have configured Paperclip on each environment:

`config/environments/development.rb`:

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    # :s3_host_name => 'REMOVE_THIS_LINE_IF_UNNECESSARY',
    :bucket => 'educartis-development',
    s3_host_alias: "educartis-production.s3.amazonaws.com",
    url: ":s3_alias_url"
  }
```

And this is what I've tried from `bundle exec rails c`:

```
irb(main):008:0> Paperclip::Storage::S3.bucket_name
NoMethodError: undefined method `bucket_name' for Paperclip::Storage::S3:Module
    from (irb):8
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/borjagvo/MyStuff/webdev/Work/Gemfeed/dev/repos/educartis/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/application.rb:183:in `block in serve'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `fork'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `serve'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

Why is it giving `undefined`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you copied this from somewhere on the Internet, including their prompt (it's choking on the `pry(main)>` part). After you start the console, just type this:

```
Paperclip::Storage::S3.bucket_name
```

Your finished prompt, then, should look like this:

```
irb(main):004:0> Paperclip::Storage::S3.bucket_name
```

Comment: sorry, but it was mine. I usually use Pry. I edited it with the result of running it without Pry.

Comment: @borjagvo How are you configuring Paperclip? Is it configured globally or per-model?

Comment: @borjagvo You are only wanting to get the bucket name, correct?

Comment: Actually I want to delete all files in that bucket.

Comment: @borjagvo Okay. I think your best option might be to get the bucket name directly from your configuration (without Paperclip involved), then use the AWS SDK (included with Paperclip by default) to delete everything in that bucket. I don't believe Paperclip has a built-in way to do that.